# How to make xsl/xslt work on included xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am checking an element value in an xml file called apple.xml using xsl/xslt. I have anther xml file called fruit.xml where I'm going to include this xml file.

```
fruit.xml:
<fruit
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

<xi:include href="apple.xml"/>
<xi:include href="banana.xml"/>
.
.
.
SOME-INTERMEDIATE-CODE

</fruit>
```

Now my apple.xml file is something like:

```
<apple>
    <color>RED</color>
    <shape>ROUND</shape>
</apple>
```

So, now I want to add a check that apple color must be RED, but I am passing my fruit.xml file to the xsl/xslt, and looks like it is not able to check conditions inside the included xml file.

I want to ask:

1. The check should work in the ideal case and I need to search for the issue elsewhere?
2. Or the idea is correct but we need to do some more stuff to make this work?

**Additional update:**
Looks like the XSLT 1.0 is not able to access the included xml tree. I tried printing an element by giving specific path like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="specific-path-of-an-element"/>
```

Nothing is getting printed.

Comment: Does the XML parser you XSLT processor uses support XInclude? Did you enable it? Is there the right XInclude namespace used (your sample doesn't even show one)?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry missed that, updated it now. Yes XInclude is supported

Comment: Just to make sure, except for the xinclude namespace, do we need to do some other stuff as well to enable it?

Comment: You haven't show as the exact way or XSLT conditions you use, how they fail and which result you expect. So hard to tell whether XInclude is just not performed or the XSLT code does not do the job you want it to do.

Comment: @MartinHonnen looks like the xinclude is not performing, as even the element value is not getting printed(means not able to access the included xml tree). But I'm curious if that is the case, why doing xinclude is not giving errors? I'm using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Looks like XInclude is supported in XSLT 2.0 and not in XSLT 1.0? https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/03/28/xinclude-processing-in-xslt-with-xipr.html

Comment: I would think that on most platforms it is a task of the underlying XML parser to perform the XInclude inclusion, on the Java platform I think XInclude is supported but you might need to enable to parser to do that. How you do that depends on the way you use XSLT or XML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am using xsltproc command tool for the linux machine, but I got your point about underlying parser. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your parser does not support XInclude, you can still access the included documents using the `document()` function. Here is a simple example:

**XML**

```
<fruit xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <xi:include href="apple.xml"/>
    <xi:include href="banana.xml"/>
    <orange/>
</fruit>
```

**apple.xml**

```
<apple>
    <color>RED</color>
    <shape>ROUND</shape>
</apple>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
exclude-result-prefixes="xi">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/fruit">
    <xsl:variable name="includes" select="document(xi:include/@href)" />
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="$includes/apple/color" />
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>RED</result>
```

---

Note that in this example, the relative URIs are resolved using the URI of the stylesheet as the base URI - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#document

Comment: I was looking and found a `--xinclude` option in `xsltproc` and looks like it is able to include the xml files. Can you confirm that this is a good way to go for as well?

Comment: I wasn't aware of this option. FWIW, I tested it just now and it appears to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the reason why but I vaguely remember in XSLT1.0 having to include the files manually. Do a select for //xi:include, read the file and replace the element with a copy of the read file's elements.

I'm guessing that 1.0 does not actually include them, or at least the version I was using didn't.

Answer (score 0):

In a processing pipeline, you can supply the XSLT processor with either the "raw" XML document (containing `xi:include` elements), or the "expanded" XML document (with `xi:include` elements replaced by the document they reference). How you achieve either or both of these effects depends very much on your specific technology stack, which you haven't told us anything about. If you want to pass the XSLT processor the expanded document, the most likely scenario is to use an XML parser that provides an option to do `xi:include` processing, and make sure this option is set.